# Overriding the devise registrations controller in a Rails mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, controller, rails-engines

I'm using devise inside a Rails engine (`my_app/components/base`) and override the registrations controller in order to forward the user to another page upon successful signup. This works quite well if I launch `my_app`, but for whatever reason devise doesn't use my custom registrations controller when launching the engine from the `spec/dummy`application that is generated for testing the engine.

The engine that uses devise is under `main_app/components/base`

My custom controller is `main_app/components/base/app/controllers/base/users/registrations_controller.rb`

```
module Base
  class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    layout 'base/application'

    def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
      fail # note: won't get called
      base.welcome_new_user_path(user)
    end    
  end
end
```

The engine's routes file is `main_app/components/base/config/routes.rb`

```
Base::Engine.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, {
    class_name: "Base::User",
    module: :devise,
    controllers: { registrations: 'base/users/registrations' }
  }
  get 'users/welcome_new_user/:id' => "users/welcome#show", as: :welcome_new_user
end
```

`rake routes` shows that the controller gets recognized:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)               base/users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                      base/users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)              base/users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                 base/users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                      base/users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                      base/users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                      base/users/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)         devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)     devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)         devise/confirmations#show
        welcome_new_user GET    /users/welcome_new_user/:id(.:format) base/users/welcome#show
```

However, the custom registrations controller won't get used in the dummy app, thus failing my RSpec tests. The same happens if I interactively use the dummy app.

Comment: Can you post your spec?

Comment: Yes, but it's not really relevant. The RSpec spec behaves exactly the same as the dummy app itself. Launching it with `rails s` doesn't use the custom controller, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Actually the issue was not that the custom registrations controller was not called, but I overrode the wrong callback function.

My intention was to forward to a 'thank you for registering' page after signup, but as my user model is confirmable it's registered, but still inactive until the user confirms his account. So the correct callback function is `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` and not `after_sign_up_path_for`.